# type null is not a Subtype of StatefulNavigationShell error

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigation-drawer, flutter-go-router, bottom-navigation-bar

I am trying to develop an app with both `a bottom navigation bar` and `a side navigation bar`. The page with the **bottom navigation** bar works fine when used as **a main page**. However, when I try to link it with my side navigation bar, I get the following error:

> Undefined name 'navigationShell'

How can I resolve this? This is the only error that I am facing.

I tried to create a getter to `navigationShell` and equate it to null. Also tried creating `a local variable`, mixing and field in the similar manner but experienced errors in all of them as well when I compiled and ran my app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.